# Как правильнее сказать

Tags: грамотная-речь

Если речь идет о женском имени Любовь, то в дательном падеже как будет правильнее: Любви или Любови?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В дательном и предложном падежах женского имени Любовь используется форма Любови.

Comment: И в родительном тоже.